# How to validate various fields for email only

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#enviarForm").attr('disabled', true);
$(":input").bind("keyup change", function(e) {
var comboVal = $('.emailrequerido').val()+$('.emailrequerido2').val()+$('.emailrequerido3').val()+$('.emailrequerido4').val()+$('.emailrequerido5').val()+$('.contactorequerido').val()+$('.gruporequerido').val();
    if(comboVal == 'nullnull'){
      $("#enviarForm").attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $("#enviarForm").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
});
```

I need to validate what is inserted in each emailrequerido1,2,3.. fields and make sure its email format. I have this function made:

```
function validarEmail(valor) {
if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/.test(valor)){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

How can I adapt this function to my code to validate each field?

Comment: Add a JSFiddle please.

Comment: **Note:** Use `.prop()` for property values instead of `.attr()`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method like this:

```
$("button").click(function () { // assuming you want to fire it on button click
    $("input[type='email']").each(function () { 
        validate($(this).val());
    });
});

function validate(email) {
    if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/.test(email)) {
        console.log("yes");
    } else {
        console.log("no");
    }
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/G6C96/) <sup>Look for output in console (F12)</sup>